# Is it possible to force the Google maps DrawingManager to complete a polyline?

Tags: google-maps

I have a user that wants to draw a polyline on a map, but he doesn't want to end it with a double-click. He wants to be able to hit a key and have the drawing complete that way. I can catch the keystroke from the keyboard, in my app, but don't seem to be able to find a way to force the DrawingManager to call the overlaycomplete event, so I don't have any way to find the completed path that has been drawn.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can be done, I have worked on a project in which the user can choose either to double click and end the polyline, or click a button "Done" to end it.

For it to work you simply have to set the DrawingMode of the drawingManager to null, like so **drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);**

This will ensure that the polyline cannot be drawn further.

Also as a safety measure you can remove the listener for drawing the polyline, but then you will have to add it once again when the user wishes to draw the polyline.

Hope it helps.

Comment: OP, if the answer helped you please accept the answer so that everyone knows that it can be resolved using the solution mentioned in the answer.